# Command works in terminal but not in script?

Tags: java, linux, unix, ubuntu

I have the following script which won't work when executed as a script, but does work when the exact same commands are entered into the terminal:

```
#! /bin/sh

cd ~/Desktop/Example/

javac Generator.java
```

The error message is:

> my_script.sh 3: my_script.sh: javac: not found

The above script is named my_script.sh and I execute it from the terminal using:

> sh my_script.sh

when I do

> echo $SHELL

in the terminal I get:

> /bin/bash

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: do you get any errors for the second command ?

Comment: @Razvan the errors relate to the second command. See above, I have included the error message now

Comment: @Razvan I believe so because I could call jmlc from another directory. How can I check for sure?

Comment: start a NEW terminal , run echo $PATH and see if the output includes a reference to the jmlc executable

Comment: @Razvan I think it is already on my path because if I type jmlc into the terminal it comes up with a version number etc. "jmlc" was not in the path but there was a reference to JML

Comment: it might be the case that only the current session has JML added to the PATH. Did you run echo $PATH in another terminal ?

Comment: The shell startup files are probably clobbering your PATH environment variable so that the command is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jmlc to your path and run the script again.

To check: Open a new shell and type 'jmc'.

Another way to get your script working is to specify the full path in your script. Replace 'jmlc' with '/full_path_here/jmlc'.

**Also** make sure that any other commands in jmlc script are also available in the path.

Comment: If I type jmlc it already comes up with a version number etc?

Comment: Ok, you could also add the full path for jmlc to your script.

Comment: Would that just be like #! <path_to_jmlc_or_jml> at the top of my script file, below the bin/sh?

Comment: Only file I could find was jmlc.bat and jmlc.1 in JML/bin but using ~Path/JML/bin/jmlc.bat Generator.java and ~Path/JML/bin/jmlc Generator.java both didnt work :(

Comment: Type `which jmlc` in the terminal to find out what file your shell is executing when you type `jmlc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also made `jmlc` available by exporting its PATH:

```
#! /bin/sh

export jmlc_bin=FULL_PATH_TO_JMLC

cd ~/Desktop/Example/

$jmlc_bin Generator.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory where your single line commands were working and save your script in that directory.

then execute

```
./my_script.sh
```